# Django installing custom app(Postgresql model)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I've installed following packages https://github.com/zacharyvoase/django-postgres via pip and virtualenv.:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/zacharyvoase/django-postgres.git
```

It was installed succesfully. I used it in my model(As described in its documentaion)

```
from django.db import models
import django_postgres as pg

USStates = pg.Enum('states_of_the_usa', ['AL', 'WY'])

class Address(pg.CompositeType):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    state = USStates()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

when I try to sync it via shell, it throws an error:

```
(virtualenv) user$ python manage.py sync_pgviews 

Unknown command: 'sync_pgviews'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Have I left something after installing an app? And is it the correct way to install django new app?

Comment: short answer is - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for management commands to work, the app has to be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. However, a basic problem that you have is that the module doesn't support [`ENUM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html) yet. Its still a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

After adding new app:

1. add app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
2. run python manage.py syncdb
3. add urls to urls.py

Perhaps you should go through this (again?) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I've read that, line by line, i can use django's models and syncing it . At first I just forgot to add it in settings.py. But now when i try to sync it throws `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Enum'`